# selected options for options_for_select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i used `options_for_select` for `select_tag` in my rails app

```
= select_tag(:salary, options_for_select( [["from 3.0000.000", 3_000_000],
                                           ["from 7.0000.000", 7_000_000]],
                                           params[:salary] ), 
                                           class:"form-select bg-light h-100")
```

how to display selected field like

```
|salary      v |
|from 3.000.000|
|from 7.000.000|
```

i tried adding `selected: 'salary'` but it doesn't work

Comment: could you please paste the full form code? and also, what is the current url? inside url it should present `?salary=from 3.000.000`

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `selected` attribute inside the `options_for_select` method like the below code:

```
= select_tag(:salary, options_for_select( [["from 3.0000.000", 3_000_000],
                                           ["from 7.0000.000", 7_000_000]],
                                           selected: params[:salary]), 
                                           class: "form-select bg-light h-100")
```

Comment: i want to set a empty value for default selected. It's like the title so the user knows what this field is for

Comment: you could use `prompt: 'Placeholder'` or `include_blank: 'Placeholder'` for this purpose.